# making a while loop with scanf inside to call functions

Tags: c

I'm trying to do an assignment for a class where we create a while loop using the `scanf` function. Basically the program is a calculator where the user should be able to type things like add 20 and my `main` function should be able to call up the functions from another `.c` then continue on in the loop.

However this is first time I am programming and I have no idea how to format or begin a loop that scans the input from the user, calls the appropriate mathematical function, applies it, then continues on in the loop.

Here's what I have done for the loop so far, which surprisingly, didn't work:

```
#include "calc.h"
#include "stdheader.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int c;
    char token[81];

    while(c != EOF){
        if (scanf("%s", token) == "clear"){
            calc.clear();
        }else{

        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

and here is a sample of the functions that it should be able to call up (or what I have for them at least)

```
int local;
local = 0;

void clear(void){
    local = 0;
    printf("\n%d", local);
}

void add(int c){
    local = local + c;
    printf("\n%d", local);
}
```

Comment: And this question is....?  What is your actual problem? Do you want somebody to complete your code? Do you want sombody to pass your assignment? Show us at least code that can be compiled.

Comment: what is the value of int c, without any initial value how u r comparing with EOF

Comment: `scanf("%s", token) == "clear"`. A good place to start would be to read carefully the man pages of the various functions that you are calling. For example, the [`scanf` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) tells you that its return value is: "the number of input items successfully matched". So straight away you should know that your comparison of its return value with a string cannot be correct. Next, in C, `==` cannot be used to compare strings. Use [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for that. You probably want `strcmp(token, "clear");`

Comment: @kaylum : That is clearly an answer, and should have been posted as such - not a comment.

Comment: @Clifford But the actual question is about using `scanf` in a loop. Since I'm not entirely clear what the OP is really asking I just pointed out some obvious errors instead.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I'm really new to all of this so i suppose it really is unclear. I don't simply want someone to solve this for me, I want to learn. I'm trying to set up a loop that scans the users input and calls the appropriate math function to be applied. All of the answers so far have been helpful, just pointing out my mistakes and explaining the functions in more detail. I've been using resources and textbooks and tutorials and anything I can get my hands on, but direct feedback like this really helps. Sorry for being a noob

Answer (score 1):

In C, strings (and arrays more generally) are not first-class data types and cannot be compared by `==`.  Moreover `scanf()` does not return a string in any case - you should read the documentation carefully.

Change:

```
if (scanf("%s", token) == "clear")
```

to:

```
scanf( "%s", token ) ;
if( strcmp( token, "clear" )
```

Additionally the test `c == EOF` is dangerous because `c` is not initialised.

```
int c = 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the details of how `scanf()` works.
[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is a good reference.

`scanf()` returns the number of tokens read, an `int` not a string. You can't compare strings with `==` anyway. To compare strings you would have to use `strcmp()` from the `string.h` library.

You don't need to prepend `calc` on the front of your `clear()` function.

There are several errors here, you're best path forward might be to try something simpler first.

Answer (score 1):

My observation:
comparing string with `==` is not a suggested one. Instead try to use `strcmp`

`scanf()` returns only integer, you are comparing it to clear in `if (scanf("%s", token) == "clear")`
changing code like
`if(scanf("%5s", token) == 1 && strcmp("clear",token) == 0)`

Also what is the initial value of `int c = ?` without this how can you compare here `while(c != EOF)`

Answer (score 0):

> However this is my first time programming and I have no idea how to format or begin a loop that scans the input from the user, calls the appropriate mathematical function, applies it, then continues on in the loop.

When you want to solve a problem that is more complex than you think that you can solve it break it up in sub-problems. First design the user interface. What should the user enter to communicate with the program.

When you have a plan integrate the features that you need:

- parsing user input
- formatting of output
- number processing (some arithmetic in your example).

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach to solve your problem.

Have array of function pointers.

```
typedef int (*func) (int,int);

func a[] = {add,sub,div,mul};
```

Have your UI like

```
printf("0 - add , 1- sub, 2 - div, 3 - mul\n");
scanf("%d",&op);

printf("Enter 2 numbers\n");
scanf("%d %d",&var1,&var2);
```

Now have

```
a[op](var1,var2);
```

Define your functions accordingly . For eg

```
int add(int x,int y)
{
  return x+y ;
}
```

and so on.